# Compression and Decompression of Argument Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, arguments, compression

I'm having trouble coming up with a way too decompress a String in Java. This is a basic Java class I'm taking so it only requires basic commands, nothing too fancy. The objective it to able to type

```
C:\>java Compress -c aaaabbbbbcc
```

in the command prompt and it will print `a4b5c2` (like it is compress the argument string).

The other objective is to type

```
C:\>java Compress -d a5b7c4
```

and it will print `aaaaabbbbbbbcccc` (like it will decompress the argument String). The decompression is the issue I'm having. Here is my code, any help I get is much appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Compress {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String originalString = scan.nextLine();
        int number = scan.nextInt();

        if (args[0].equals("-c")) {
            System.out.println("compress");
            compress(originalString);
        }

        else if (args[0].equals("-d")) {
            System.out.println("decompress");
            decompress(originalString);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Compress program by Kelsey Faram");
            System.out.println("usage: java Compress [-c,-d] < inputFile > outputFile");
        }
    }

    public static void compress(String originalString) {
        int count = 0;
        char comp = originalString.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++) {
            originalString.charAt(i);

            if (comp == originalString.charAt(i))
                count++;
            else {
                System.out.print(comp + "" + count);
                comp = originalString.charAt(i);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(comp + "" + count);
    }

    public static void decompress(String originalString) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. Hint: use Integer.parseInt().

Comment: `The decompression is the issue I'm having.` Can we know more about this issue? In which part of code you stuck? What and how ware you trying to achieve and how was it different from expected results?

Comment: no, we wont do your homework

Comment: im not asking for you to do my homework im asking for hints like what commands to use like what Zemzela did, thanks by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Quick Code for you..


public static void decompress(String originalString)
{
        StringBuffer finalString = new StringBuffer();;
        char previouschar = originalString.charAt(0);
        for(int i=1; i < originalString.length(); i+=2){
                for(int j = 0 ; j< Integer.parseInt(""+originalString.charAt(i));j++) {
                    finalString.append(previouschar);
                }               
                if(i+1 < originalString.length())
                {
                    previouschar=originalString.charAt(i+1);
                }
        }
        System.out.println(finalString.toString());
}
```